# Theos Building The Project

Tags: macos, jailbreak, theos

i am facing compile Theos project on mac terminal. i am used OSX10.8.5
i have done all work for create Theos jailbroken Project

1. Install the latest Ios7.1 Sdk
2. Setting Up The Environment Variables.

   ```
   $ export THEOS=/opt/theos
   $ echo $THEOS
   ```

3.Getting theos

```
    $ svn co http://svn.howett.net/svn/theos/trunk $THEOS
```

4.Getting ldi

```
    $ sudo curl -s http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3157793/ldid > ~/Desktop/ldid
    $ chmod +x ~/Desktop/ldid
    $ sudo mv ~/Desktop/ldid $THEOS/bin/ldid
```

5.Install dpkg  (Mac Port)

```
    $ sudo port install dpkg
```

1. Creating A New Project

   ```
   $ sudo THEOS/bin/nic.pl
   ```
2. set environment

   ```
   $ export THEOS=/opt/theos/
   $ export SDKVERSION=7.1
   $ export THEOS_DEVICE_IP=192.168.1.151
   ```
3. Compile project

   ```
   $ make
   ```

when i compile the theos project then mac terminal through error.

```
    Making all for application fooProject...
    mkdir: obj: Permission denied
    make[1]: *** [obj] Error 1
    make: *** [fooProject.all.application.variables] Error 2
```

please suggest to me. where am i wrong. i am new on theos so i trouble for solve this problem last 2 days.

Thank you

Comment: OK, so the `Makefile` is trying to create a directory (`obj`) but getting *permission denied*.  Where is it trying to create that directory?  (use `make -n` to see what is being run).

Comment: Thank so much for your quick replay. yes i run make -n command is execute but through this error [ -d "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk" ] || { echo "Your current SYSROOT, \"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk\", appears to be missing."; exit 1; }
while i have already set iPhoneOS7.1.sdk by this command export SDKVERSION=7.1

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the same error you posted in your question.

Comment: this error occur after run this command   make -n

Comment: and make -n command execute perfectly.

Comment: Does it work if you use `sudo make` to build ?

Comment: no. i cann't use sudo command. makefile restrict for sudo keyword.

Comment: Then maybe you should have created the project without using sudo (which works for me, and allows me to build without the "Permission Denied" error)

Answer (score 1):

I made a proper answer because it is more visible than just a single comment.
I just reprocuded the error by creating a project using your commands.
You need to create your project without using `sudo` (just type `THEOS/bin/nic.pl`), and then you'll be allowed to compile it with `make`, otherwise it will throw a `Permission Denied` as the files will be owned by the System Administrator.